# Enums for JOI scheme validation

Tags: node.js, types, enums, joi

I have a JOI validation scheme which some values which I need in some other scheme's and other places too, so I placed all those values in a seperated file and import them in the scheme.

Scheme:

```
const ENUMS = require(path.join(__dirname, 'enums'))
const Product = Joi.object({
   name: Joi.string(),
   category: Joi.string().valid(ENUMS.validProductCategory),
   description: Joi.string().allow(ENUMS.empty)
})
```

Enums.js

```
module.exports.productCategory = ['JEWEL', 'WATCH', 'EARRING']
module.exports.empty = '', null
```

The problem is that `Joi.valid()` and `Joi.allow()` does not accept arrays as values (see https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.5.0#anyallowvalues). The values in the function needs to passed as `.valid('a', 'b')`
I don't know how the let that values return from the enums file. I have tried some ways (like the `module.exports.empty`) and with the spreading (`...`) options.

I don't get it to work either, so I'm wondering how I can return the string in the right format to reuse it?

Comment: Have tried to use `.apply(...)`? Something like `Joi.string().valid.apply(Joi, ENUMS.validProductCategory)`

Comment: @Marc I didn't try it, and it looks its works fine for the ```valid()``` function, but for the ```alow()``` functions it doesn't. ```Joi.string().allow.apply(Joi, ENUMS.empty)``` gives ```TypeError: this._values is not a function``` any idea how?

Comment: @Marc I changed all exports in enums to an array by the way. So ```ENUMS.empty``` is ```['', null]```

Comment: `module.exports.empty = '', null` is not valid. `.apply` accepts as first a "this" scope & as second argument a array. You can read more about apply on mdn.

Answer (score 2):

if you have an enum e.g

```
enum ValidStringsEnum {
    DESCRIPTION_ONE = "description one",
    DESCRIPTION_TWO = "description two",
}
```

you could do:

```
description: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(ValidStringsEnum))
```